# Ways to render a login/logout button or menu with node.js/express.js and backbone.js

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, authentication, express, authorization

Is there some simple example of how to render a login and logout button or menu using node.js with express and backbone without using a jade template? I want to show a login button if the user is not logged in and a logout button when the user is logged in.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to have some sort of variable or session data from the server that tells you if the user is logged in, and then pass that data to whatever is rendering your page, and using Jade or EJS is ususally a lot easier than trying to pass values to the HTML yourself, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I used a simple method of setting a cookie when the used is in logged in state. That cookie is referred using Javascript to make the toggle operation.